# Get Window Title from Kernel Driver? C Programming

Tags: c, winapi

Searching for an way to get Window Name by Driver, Like FindWindow, GetWindowText. And yes I do need it from kernel mode and not user mode.

Comment: I don't think the kernel is involved in managing those parts of windows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `WND` structures **are** managed by the kernel, specifically the window manager that lives in the NT Executive, ntoskrnl.exe.

Comment: Maybe, but a driver seems like an inappropriate place to make such GUI interface calls.  I mean, it's a driver - it doesn't even know what process/thread it has interrupted.

Comment: I wasn't recommending anything, just pointing out that Barmar's (now upvoted) statement is blatantly wrong.

Comment: Im able to get Image Path Name, but I do need the Window Name of the App, is there really no way?

Comment: You have very likely misdiagnosed the problem you **really** need to solve. While there is a 1:1 mapping between processes and and executable image path, there is no such mapping for windows. A process can have zero or more (top-level) windows. With that out of the way, what **problem** are you trying to solve?